# How to create an alias of a group in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We are using a product which integrates with Active Directory via LDAP.

Due the way the integration works we need 2 DNs for every user.

I have been researching and I think this may be possible via alias (objectClass:alias) however I can't find any information on how to actually create these in AD.

This is sort of what I want to do:

```
dn: cn=UsersAlias,dc=internal,dc=company,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: alias
objectClass: top
objectClass: extensibleObject
uid: UsersAlias
aliasedObjectName: cn=Users,dc=internal,dc=company,dc=com
```

This will mean user Joe Bloggs will end up with 2 DNs, e.g.

```
CN=Joe Bloggs,CN=Users,DC=internal,DC=company,DC=com
CN=Joe Bloggs,CN=UsersAlias,DC=internal,DC=company,DC=com
```

Comment: *"Due the way the integration works we need 2 DNs for every user."* - Why? I've never heard of this need before.

Comment: @GabrielLuci the integration is creating objects in another system with DN as the foreign key, the problem is we are trying to map the users job and user as 2 seperate objects in the destination system.